# Profile Picture Problem

Tags: bug, gravatar

Profile pics from SO and the other sites are broken this morning for me, and the problem is also making my [flair show up as a broken image](http://kaiseradvisor.blogspot.com).

EDIT - I've cleared the cache and tried in Chrome and IE.

EDIT 2 - My fault - My bloody company firewall started blocking gravatar this morning. Sorry.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you tried clearing the cache?

Update: What error are you seeing from Firebug when the browser tries to download the images? (I'm just wondering if someone is blocking gravatar where you are.)

Comment: Have you tried using jQuery?

Comment: I see you're trying to use an old meme, you should totally drop that and try jQuery.

Comment: I've cleared the cache and tried in Chrome and IE