# Avatars not being displayed

Tags: support, gravatar

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Profile Picture Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/27714/profile-picture-problem)

Is there something wrong with the site, none of the avatars are being displayed?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's a problem on your side. Hit CTRL+F5. If they still do not show up, maybe your employer blocked gravatar.com with some filter rules.

Comment: Thanks, you were right gravatar.com is blocked, must have been an update in the weekend, was not blocked last week.