# Profile picture display problem

Tags: bug, images, profile-picture

## Bug

[image: user profile pic not shown]

User [Saketh Malyala](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/250220/saketh-malyala)'s profile picture *isn't* displayed.

## My Observations

Profile picture's image location: https://graph.facebook.com/384396958435934/picture?type=large

Opening this URL, one is prompted to download a JPEG file.

[image: Saketh Malyala's profile picture]
Saketh Malyala's profile picture downloaded from the above link.

## My attempts for searching similar questions

1. [Profile Picture Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/27714/259305): I'm using Firefox 66.0.2 (64-bit) on Xubuntu 18.04 LTS.  I've tried clearing browser cache, but the profile picture is still *broken*.
2. [Where's My Profile Picture?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/253117/259305): The accepted answer suggests the possibility of image URL corruption.  However, the above downloaded JPEG file shows that the URL can deliver the image content.
3. [Facebook imported picture is breaking the network profile design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/167416/259305): The linked question is also about profile picture display error for images from Facebook.  However, this problem is *different* since this is a *missing content* error, whereas the linked post is about a *content layout* problem.